# '[log] AsyncError<List<Product>>(error: Connection refused, stackTrace: #0' while fetching data

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I'm trying to return data from my future provider and use it inside my GridView widget but I got that error.
The URL is returning status and data: `{"status":"success","data":[{"items_id":5,etc}}`

Here is my fake_product_repository.dart:

```
class ProductsRepository {
  Future<List<Product>> fetchProductsList() async {
    final url =
        Uri.parse('http://localhost:80/ecommerceflutter/items/items.php');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      List<Product> products = [];
      for (var productData in jsonData) {
        Product product = Product.fromJson(
            productData); // Replace with your own deserialization logic
        products.add(product);
      }
      return products;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch products');
    }
  }
}

final productsRepositoryProvider = Provider<ProductsRepository>((ref) {
  // You can initialize your repository here if needed
  return ProductsRepository();
});

final productsListProvider = FutureProvider<List<Product>>((ref) async {
  final repository = ref.watch(productsRepositoryProvider);
  final products = await repository.fetchProductsList();
  return products;
});
```

**This is *product_grid.dart* used my in *main.dart*:**

```
class ProductsGrid extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ProductsGrid({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final productsListValue = ref.watch(productsListProvider);

    // return Text("heafasd");
    return productsListValue.when(
      loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: (err, stack) => Text('Error $err'),
      data: (products) => ProductsLayoutGrid(
        itemCount: products.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          final product = products[index];
          return ProductCard(
            product: product,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductsLayoutGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsLayoutGrid(
      {super.key, required this.itemCount, required this.itemBuilder});
  final int itemCount;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, int) itemBuilder;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) itemBuilder(context, i),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Also in case I have multiple requests should I create Future provider as I did, is there anyway to wrap everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was changing the url to `http://10.0.2.2/ecommerceflutter/items/items.php`

Answer (score 0):

As for the response, `data` contains the items.

```dart
....
final jsonData = json.decode(response.body)['data']; //this will return list 
List<Product> products = [];
```

Comment: great but I'm still having the same error

Comment: try to wrap with try-catch and check the current error